# about twitter autolink

Tags: regex, api, twitter

I have read [twitter's autolink testcases](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-conformance/blob/master/autolink.yml) but still can't find my answer.

I'm making an application and post updates to twitter's API server, which contains one url link.

I want to keep autolink alive, but there is a chance that the following case happens

```
messagetexthttp://example.com
```

I do not want to insert space or colon between messagetext and the url. (letter count is well calculated to be 140 so..)

In this case, the autolink dead.

Any solutions?

Comment: Why don't you want to insert a space? What kind of solution do you expect? You included a regex tag, you could of course look for `\whttp`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Delete `http://` part from the URL. Likely, Twitter will still identify the URL and you will gain more space instead of losing.